# How to manipulate a cos(x) Maclaurin series?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a series as follows:
$$1- \frac{3^2}{4^2 \times 2!} +\frac{3^4}{4^4 \times 4!}-\frac{3^6}{4^6 \times 6!}$$

I understand that this is a different form of a cos(x) Maclaurin series. Replace the x with the 3 and it matches the numerator. I am unsure how to manipulate the cos(x) to get the extra $$4^{2n}$$ in with the factorial in the denominator.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First time using TeX, sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: Hint: which $x$ satisfies $3^{2n}/4^{2n}=x^{2n}$?

Comment: @J.G. Hmm... I think I'm kind of seeing it. $$(\frac{3}{4})^{2n}$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{i\ge 0}(-)^i\frac{3^{2i}}{4^{2i}(2i)!}
$$
is a special case of
$$
\cos x = \sum_{i\ge 0}(-)^i\frac{1}{(2i)!}x^{2i},
$$
at $x=3/4$,
$$
\sum_{i\ge 0}(-)^i\frac{3^{2i}}{4^{2i}(2i)!} =\cos(3/4).
$$